# Main backtesting & trading solutions: QuantFactory, Deltix, etc.

Tags: backtesting, algorithmic-trading, software, trading-systems

What are the most used/mature/promising commercial solutions today which handle backtesting/ automated trading needs?

I'm talking about vertical product suites like [QuantFactory](http://www.quanthouse.com/?q=node/19) or [Deltix](http://www.deltixlab.com/) which address market data capture, historical data, CEP, backtesting, trading, etc. (I would be more specifically interested about the backtesting part though.)

- What are the big players here?
- Do you have any feedback (pro/cons) about theses solutions?
- What is the cost of integrating such a solution into an existing ecosystem?
- Are they customizable enough to handle very specific needs?

I know that sounds like a lot a different questions, but I'm trying to get a general feeling about these tools (are they popular, useful, who use them, for what, etc.)

Answer (score 8):

Some LinkedIn groups are particularily adequate to post these questions.
Your question has already been asked in "Automated Trading Strategies" at this URL: [Seeking input on QuantFactory, Deltix and 4thStory: Professional end-to-end Automated Trading Solutions](http://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=1813979&type=member&item=43835799&qid=80b45454-3b0b-461e-8cf9-6f3f6ed31b4c&goback=.gmp_1813979).

Feel free to let us know the state of your research.

Comment: LinkedIn requires an account to view the results. Can you summarize the comments here?

Comment: @Chrisaycock, That thread was all over the place with answers in 3 categories: "too buggy for the price" "works just right" and "contact me for details."

Answer (score 7):

I can share my own experience working with the Deltix product suite. As a research and development platform it's very feature rich with support for every back-testing mode there is (BBO, Trade, Midprice, Bar, Level 2 Order Book) and advanced optimization modes (walk-forward, genetic, mean-variance, portfolio optimization, etc). I have built components and external back-office tools to integrate with my strategies. This is easy by building around their central data warehouse (TimeBase) from which a strategy receives input (market data) and can optionally send output to for other strategies and components to pick-up in real time (custom data and inter-strategy event handling). As far as the cost of integrating it into an existing ecosystem, they now have a retail offering (which I'm currently using for freelance development) that is cheaper and a good place to start learning the APIs and porting existing strategies. You'll then have a clear cut upgrade path to the full blown product suite when your work is re-qualified as "institutional".

Answer (score 1):

There are many:

- Marketctera
- iQuantTrader
- CEP Trader
- IQBroker
- Algo Trade
- ActiveQuant
- TradeLink
- Orc
- FlexTrade
- Portware
- Apama
- Aleri
- etc

Try a Google search to find more.

Comment: some of these aren't backtesting