# Overview of software companies in the industry

Tags: reference-request, software

I am looking for overview references on software companies that develop applications in the following domains:

- asset and portfolio management
- risk management
- derivatives pricing
- trading
- quant modelling

I am also interested in different approaches, like:

- buy and sell side products
- commercial and open source products
- big established players and agile innovative new players

The references should give an idea about what the products are capable of and their position in the industry.

**Important** 
I am interested in references that give a balanced overview (advertising links to individual companies will not be tolerated here! If the answers as such give a balanced overview themselves this is of course fine).

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [this question](http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/631/2278)

Comment: @classifire Thank you, although this is a very specific subclass of the companies I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry but I find this an incredibly broad question. I am sure at least 500-1000 companies would fall under this umbrella. Its almost as if you ask for companies that develop C# code.

Comment: It's already hard enough finding a comprehensive sw list, let alone a comparison; for a partial list check bobsguide's directory. For comparisons Lupus offers something, although not for free.

Comment: I don't want to have a list with 1.000 companies but some guidance and overview. There must be some research and analysts out there who cover these topics.

Comment: @Quartz This seems to be a first lead. Could you please form an answer out of you comment - thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I dont even know of comprehensive SW lists; one of the best ones probably being [bobsguide directory](http://www.bobsguide.com/directory.html) (subdivided in specific topics). Another one is at [Marketwiki](http://www.marketswiki.com/mwiki/Category%3aIndependent_Software_Vendors). [Lepus](http://www.lepus.com/research/system-selection/) also offers a through comparison of software in some of the mentioned areas, and keeps lists with features. For HFT there's [HFTReview's](http://www.hftreview.com/pg/main/solutions-directory) directory.